# Why does function pointer in c does not have to be pointer at all?

Tags: c, function-pointers, implicit-conversion, function-declaration

Having this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int do_op(int (*op)(int,int),int a, int b){ return op(a,b); }
/*int do_op(int (op)(int,int),int a,int b){return op(a,b);} */
int add(int a, int b){ return a+b; }
int mul(int a, int b){ return a*b; }

int main(){
    printf("add:%i;mul:%i\n",do_op(add,5,10),do_op(mul,5,10));
}
```

From what I know about function pointer so far, is their "type" is of return value's type. (Does not know how it is implemented in gas, wheter the return value is in `%rax` before `ret`? just an detail), however what is the point of a reference to a function, when it does not have to be reference at all? What does it mean, when it is *not* pointer? (like `(op)`), is then the function used by *value* (not address)? But function in general does not have *value*, it has only start address in `%rbi` and after it finishes, it is retuned back to upper function by `ret`, so what does it mean in c, a function "pointer" is not *pointer*? (give some examples please)

The question is relating to the comment in the code, where the `(op)` part is not a pointer, but still work. So is it a pointer or not?

Comment: The question text does not make much sense to me,  could you perhaps indicate what part of the code you posted you don't understand?

Comment: @autistic456 It is unclear why do you have decided that function pointer is not pointer?

Comment: @M.M, in comments, there is a alternative, where the `(op)` part is not `(*op)`, and thus it is not a pointer

Comment: @autistic456 in a function parameter, a parameter of function type is adjusted to pointer-to-function

Comment: @M.M there is case however, where `(op)` is not allowed -> when function returns function: `int (*f(int))(int,int)` is the only way. I  cannot do `int (f(int))(int,int)`, so you are not 100% correct.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow there is case however, where `(op)` is not allowed -> when function returns function: `int (*f(int))(int,int)` is the only way. I  cannot do `int (f(int))(int,int)`, so you are not 100% correct.

Comment: @autistic456 Functions may not return functions. They may return pointers to functions. The same way as functions may not returns arrays. They may return pointers to arrays.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I was not talking about semantic. These are pretty basic conception you do not have to explain me. The question was purely about *syntax*. Because in one case (beign as function argument), there is a implicit converstion by compiler from `(op)` to `(*op)`. But in *declaration* which is the case it the comment `int (*f(int))(int,int)`, there is no such converstion. So that is what contradicts each other, because compiler does only partial job for you, but in another context, it is wholly up to you, to watch the semantic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The type of a function pointer is not its return type.  It is the type of the function pointed to.

In the case of the parameter `int (*op)(int,int)`, the type of `op` is "pointer to function which takes an `int` and an `int`, and returns `int`".

You could also define the parameter as `int op(int,int)` in which case the type of `op` is "function which takes an `int` and an `int`, and returns `int`".

Because function pointers point to code, they don't have a "value" in the sense that objects do.  In fact, anyplace you specify an expression with a function type it is automatically converted to a pointer to a function.  So you can declare the parameter `op` as  `int (*op)(int,int)` or  `int op(int,int)` and they will be exactly the same.

Section 6.3.2.1p4 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) says the following regarding function types:

> A *function  designator* is  an  expression  that  has  function 
>   type.   Except  when  it  is  the operand of the `sizeof` operator,
>   the `_Alignof` operator, or the unary `&` operator, a function
>   designator with type ‘‘function returning *type*’’ is converted to an
>   expression that has type ‘‘pointer to function returning *type*’’.

Section 6.7.6.3p8 also says the following regarding a function type as a parameter:

> A declaration of a parameter as ‘‘function returning *type*’’ shall be
>   adjusted to ‘‘pointer to function returning *type*’’, as in 6.3.2.1.

It is because of this that a parameter of function type is allowed.  A variable of function type that is not a parameter is not useful because it can't be initialized or assigned.

Comment: the first case `(*op)(int,int)` could be assignable, whereas the second (`int op(int,int)`) not (it is function declaration I think). And as in my case it is used inside another function as argument and thus **has to**be *assignable*, but still, does not need to have `*`, which usually indicates pointer. So if it always *points* to a first instruction of the code, then why it does not have to have the `*` (in assignable context)?

Comment: @autistic456 See my edit.  A parameter of function type is the same as a pointer to a function.

Comment: there is case however, where `(op)` is not allowed -> when function returns function: `int (*f(int))(int,int)` is the only way. I  cannot do `int (f(int))(int,int)`, so you are not 100% correct.

Answer (score 2):

> From what I know about function pointer so far, is their "type" is of return value's type.

No.  I know we've addressed this issue in comments and answers to some of your previous questions.  The type of a function pointer is different from the pointed-to function's return type, and also different from a pointer to the function's return type.  The type of a function pointer is a particular function pointer type.  All function pointer types have a return type as one of their attributes.  They also convey information about the number and type of the function's parameters.  Function pointer type names also differ from all object pointer type names.  In the present case, the type name is `int (*)(int,int)`, which I'm sure you see is different from both `int` and `int *`.

> what is the point of a reference to a function, when it does not have to be reference at all?

The reason for using a function pointer (not "reference") is to allow different actual functions to be selected at runtime.  In your case, different calls to function `do_op()` can be made to perform different operations.  That's no big deal in the example, because `do_op()` does nothing but call the specified function one time, and the choice of operation is hardcoded into each call, but it would be more interesting if, say, the choice of operation were dictated by user input.

And of course the argument corresponding to the function pointer parameter has to be a (compatible) function pointer.  C does not make any exception to its type matching rules in such cases.

> What does it mean, when it is not pointer? (like (`op`)),

But it *is* a pointer.  Wherever an expression of function type appears in a valid C expression, other than as the operand of a unary `&` operator, it is automatically converted to a pointer to the function it identifies.  That applies to the identifier of the function being called, too: the function-call operator, `()`, is an operator on function *pointers*.  You can regard this as a convenience feature: you do not need to use the `&` operator to obtain a a function pointer.  This makes code a bit easier to write and read.  C does not provide any way to express accessing a function value.

> The question is relating to the comment in the code, where the (op) part is not a pointer, but still work. So is it a pointer or not?

Parameter `op` of function `do_op()` is a pointer to a function that expects two arguments of type `int` and returns an `int`.  In each call to that function, the corresponding argument is a function identifier.  As expressions of function type, these are automatically converted to pointers.  The resulting function pointers are of the expected type.

Answer (score 1):

> From what I know about function pointer so far, is their "type" is of
>   return value's type.

From the C Standard (6.2.5 Types)

> A function type is characterized by its return type and the number and
>   types of its parameters.

For example the type of these functions

```
int add(int a, int b){ return a+b; }
int mul(int a, int b){ return a*b; }
```

is `int( int, int )`. That is to describe a function you have to specify what it accepts and what it returns.

> What does it mean, when it is not pointer? (like (op))

In this declaration

```
int do_op(int (op)(int,int),int a,int b){return op(a,b);}
```

the parameter `op` has the type `int( int, int )`. The compiler adjusts a parameter having a function type to a parameter having the type of pointer to the function.

So for example these two declarations

```
int do_op(int (op)(int,int),int a,int b);
int do_op(int (*op)(int,int),int a,int b);
```

that can be rewritten without parameter names like

```
int do_op(int (int,int),int ,int );
int do_op(int (*)(int,int),int ,int );
```

are equivalent and declare the same one function. You may include the both declarations in your program though the compiler can issue a warning  that there are redundant declarations.

From the C Standard (6.7.6.3 Function declarators (including prototypes))

> 8 A declaration of a parameter as ‘‘function returning type’’ shall be
>   adjusted to ‘‘pointer to function returning type’’, as in 6.3.2.1.

When a function is used as an argument like in this statement

```
printf("add:%i;mul:%i\n",do_op(add,5,10),do_op(mul,5,10));
```

then it is implicitly converted to pointer to the function. The value of the pointer is the entry point of the function where the control can be passed.

From the C Standard (6.3.2.1 Lvalues, arrays, and function designators)

> 4 A function designator is an expression that has function type.
>   Except when it is the operand of the sizeof operator65) or the unary &
>   operator, a function designator with type ‘‘function returning type’’
>   is converted to an expression that has type ‘‘pointer to function
>   returning type’’.

Comment: Why are they equivalent? there is no difference between `(*)(int,int)` and `()(int,int)`? I think there is, I do not know what compiler does, or what rules applys but these two types are not the same

Comment: @autistic456 I wrote in my answer that the compiler adjusts the type of the parameter from a function type to pointer to the function.

Comment: But before they do so, How could even exits `()(int,int)`, when there does not exist *value* of function? only `(*)(int)(int)` makes sense, since that is really pointer to the first address of instruction, but the former does not make sense

Comment: @autistic456 It is a declaration of a type of a parameter like for example  int( int, int ) the same way as you have to specify types of other parameters.

Comment: @autistic456 When a function is passed as an argument it is converted to pointer to its entry point.

Answer (score 0):

Function pointers differ from data pointers in that they point to code, not to data. So the *value* of the pointer is going to be the memory location for the beginning on the function. Since the *value* is already and address in memory, there is no reason to deference it like we would a normal pointer.

This article seems to have a clear explanation of the concept with good examples if you want more details:
[Function Pointers in C - GeeksforGeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/function-pointer-in-c/#:~:text=1)%20Unlike%20normal%20pointers%2C%20a,used%20to%20get%20functions'%20address.)

Comment: The OP does not seem to be asking about why the pointer is not dereferenced.  They are asking about why the identifiers `add` and `mul`, which designate functions, can be used as arguments corresponding to a function pointer, even though they designate functions rather than pointers.

Answer (score 0):

A function pointer in c is always a pointer to the first instruction of the function.
A function value in c (the value of applying * to a function pointer) is also implemented the same as a function pointer, leading to this confusion.
In the end functions will always be pointers to code and the compiler is just ignoring whether you used a c function pointer or value.

Comment: C says absolutely nothing about how function pointer values correspond to machine instructions (and I don't see any other kind of "instruction" you might mean).  What you appear to have in mind is very common, but not necessary. Additionally, function values are in no way the same as function pointers, much the same way that arrays are not pointers.  That there are automatic *conversions* involving both functions and arrays does not mean that these are pointers themselves.

Comment: @JohnBollinger there is case however, where `(op)` is not allowed -> when function returns function: `int (*f(int))(int,int)` is the only way. I  cannot do `int (f(int))(int,int)`, so you are not 100% correct.

Comment: @autistic456, I have no idea why you think that the fact that C does not allow one to declare a function that returns a function contradicts anything I have said here.  Did you mean to address that comment to the author of this answer (Dani)?

Comment: @JohnBollinger it is not about what `C` does, the question was about why both `(*op)` and `(op)` is valid in the *case* above. But in this case I just commented it is *not* valid. These are two situations which contradics

Comment: @autistic456, I did not anywhere claim that `(op)` and `(*op)` were *syntactically* interchangeable.  They are not.  In particular, they are not interchangeable in declarations.  But all of my previous commentary has been about their use in *expressions*, which is what you asked about, and how automatic *semantic* conversions explain the phenomenon you highlight in the question.

Comment: @JohnBollinger ok. It is just strange for me the fact, the in argument context (case from the original post), there is a implicit conversion from `(op)` to `(*op)` by compiler, but in *declaration*, you have to watch the semantic by yourself. So with this in mind, the compiler does only partial job, when it helps you in argument context, but anywhere else, its up to you